# Encapsulating multiple objects of a class in another class in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes which resemble the following.

```
class Hand
{
public:
    func1();
    func2();
    ...
    func20();
private:
    Hand();
    ~Hand();
    Hand(const Hand& that);
    void operator=(Hand const&);
    friend class Body;
};

class Body
{
public:
    Body();
    ~Body();
    Hand * const &left_hand;
    Hand * const &right_hand;
private:
    Hand * _left_hand;
    Hand * _right_hand;
};

Body::Body()
:left_hand(_left_hand)
:right_hand(_right_hand)
{
    _left_hand = new Hand();
    _right_hand = new Hand();
};
```

This follows the Hand/Body relation. The hand belongs to the Body. -

1. User cannot create/delete a Hand object.
2. User cannot create a copy of the Hand object belonging to the Body.
3. User cannot modify the left hand and right hand pointers of the Body object.

However, my colleagues say that to allow the user to directly call methods of a member object (in this case `body->left_hand->func1()`) is a bad design.

One suggestion was to use a getter funtion eg `getLeftHand()` which returns `Hand * const` instead of a read only public variable left_hand.

Another was to create wrapper functions for each Hand functions like

```
class Body
{
    Body();
    ~Body();
    leftHandfunc1();
    rightHandfunc1();
    leftHandfunc2();
    rightHandfunc2();
    ...
    leftHandfunc20();
    rightHandfunc20();
private:
    Hand * _left_hand;
    Hand * _right_hand;
};
```

And

```
Body::leftHandfunc1()
{
    _left_hand->func1();
}
```

However, as you can see, 20 methods of Hand equals 40 wrapper functions in Body. And this list is expected to grow. Should I go with this approach?

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: What about separate creation and interface of `Hand` by introducing an abstract base class (the interface)?

Comment: your `class Body` has only `private` memebrs and no `public` is that a typo?

Comment: If you want to just expose all the functionality of the hands through the interface of the body, just make the hands public members.

Comment: BTW, I would expose only `Hand&` not `Hand*`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley . So calling `body->left_hand->func1()`  in the application would be OK?

Comment: @tobi303 . You are right. Corrected the mistake.

Comment: @NPat: Or `body.left_hand.func1()`, unless the hands are detachable.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?  You could declare the members without pointers.  Pointers complicate programs tremendously.

Comment: Write inline accessor functions. `Hand * const &left_hand;` is a "clever" trick that shows you know what a reference is, wastes memory, and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface for `Hand` that exposes the publicly available functionality (only for read access):

```
struct IHand
{
public:
    virtual void func1() const = 0;
    virtual void func2() const = 0;
    ...
    virtual void func20() const = 0;
    virtual ~IHand() {}
};
```

---

```
class Hand : public IHand
{
public:
    void func1() const;
    void func2() const;
    ...
    void func20() const;
private:
    Hand();
    ~Hand();
    Hand(const Hand& that);
    void operator=(Hand const&);
    friend class Body;
};
```

In you `Body` class you can safely hand out `const` reference getters for `_left_hand` and `_right_hand` as follows:

```
class Body
{
public:
    Body();
    ~Body();
    const IHand& left_hand() const { return _left_hand; }
    const IHand& right_hand() const { return _right_hand; }
private:
    Hand _left_hand;
    Hand _right_hand;
};
```

Clients can access the interface like:

```
Body body;

body.left_hand().func1();
body.right_hand().func20();
```

This design would match for all your constraints:

> 1. User cannot create/delete a Hand object.
> 2. User cannot create a copy of the Hand object belonging to the Body.
> 3. User cannot modify the left hand and right hand pointers of the Body object.

I wasn't sure about your last point, what is meant with *modify*. So I made everything `const` in the interface as a precaution.

Comment: By point 3, I meant that body.left_hand = body.right_hand should not be possible. The earlier revision worked for me. I used pointers because the constructor of `Hand` needs to be called at the end of constructor of `Body`. I pass certain variables to the `Hand` constructor which are calculated in `Body`  constructor. Likewise, need `Hand` to be destroyed before `Body` destructor begins. If this is possible with your current solution, that would be great.

Comment: @ShaunakGupte _"Likewise, need Hand to be destroyed before Body destructor begins."_ It's already like this with my example code.